# Unable to implement BufferUntil RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java

Trying to implement `BufferUntil` for `Observable` *(that is, buffer elements and emit buffered list whenever some criteria is met)*

Implemented for RxNET

*Define :*

```
public static IObservable<IList<TSource>> BufferUntil<TSource>(
              this IObservable<TSource> source, 
              Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        var published = source.Publish().RefCount();
        return published.Buffer(() => published.Where(predicate));
    }
```

*Using :*

```
var list = new List<char> { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'c' };
list
    .ToObservable()
    .BufferUntil(c => c == 'c')
    .Subscribe(c => c.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine));
```

*Result :*

Works fine. Emits 2 `IList` of `char` : `['a','b','c']`  and `['d','e','c']`

Trying to implement exact same for RxJava

*Define :*

```
public <T extends Object> Observable<List<T>> bufferUntil(
        Observable<T> source,
        final Func1<T, Boolean> bufferClosingCriteria) {

    final Observable<T> published = source.publish().refCount();
    return published.buffer(new Func0<Observable<T>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<T> call() {
            return published.filter(bufferClosingCriteria);
        }
    });
}
```

*Using :*

```
Character[] arr = {'a','b','c','d','e','c'};

bufferUntil(rx.Observable.from(arr), new Func1<Character, Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean call(Character character) {
        return character == 'c';
    }
}).subscribe(new Action1<List<Character>>() {
    @Override
    public void call(List<Character> o) {
        for (int i = 0; i < o.size(); ++i)
           Log.d("LL", o.get(i).toString());
    }
});
```

*Result :*

It emits **3 Empty List**

What is wrong with RxJava implementation and/or how to fix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that RxJava works differently due to being synchronous by default whereas Rx.NET has asynchronous sources.

What happens in RxJava is that when the boundary subscribes to the refCount, the upstream starts immediately emitting all the characters, runs through the character array and the boundary keeps signalling whenever it sees a "c". At this point, the buffer operator hasn't even subscribed to the same refCount source and never sees any data coming from it.

In Rx.NET, as far as I understand, the fact that List.ToObservable goes onto another thread to emit items of the array, that gives enough time for the original thread to have both the buffer and its boundary get subscribed to the RefCount.

If you added a small delay `source.delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).publish().refCount()` you see the data and lists coming through, however, the contents of the list will still differ:

```
[a, b]
[c, d, e]
[c]
```

The reason for this is that in RxJava, the boundary Observable gets subscribed first followed by the buffer subscriber thus when a "c" comes along, it reaches the boundary first which triggers a buffer-split and then the buffer operator gets the value "c" and stores it in a new buffer.

To make sure the operator works with synchronous source, you have to use `publish(Func1)` instead of refCount:

```
public static <T extends Object> Observable<List<T>> bufferUntil(
        Observable<T> source,
        final Func1<T, Boolean> bufferClosingCriteria) {

    return source.publish(o -> o.buffer(() -> o.filter(bufferClosingCriteria)));
}
```

This `publish()` variant makes sure every potential consumer of "o" is set up before the source is consumed.

Reordering the subscriptions to make sure "c" ends up at the end of the buffer is a bit more involved:

```
return source.publish(o -> {
    PublishSubject<Object> ps = PublishSubject.create();
    return o.buffer(() -> ps)
            .mergeWith(Observable.defer(() -> {
                o.filter(bufferClosingCriteria).subscribe(ps);
                return Observable.empty();
            }))
            .filter(list -> !list.isEmpty());
});
```

Yields:

```
[a, b, c]
[d, e, c]
```